Is a collection of linear transformations of Gaussian random variables a matrix-Gaussian random variable?
Let $\Theta$ be an $\mathbb R^n$-valued Gaussian random variable with mean vector $\mu$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma$. For some $A_1,A_2\in\mathcal M_{m\times n}(\mathbb R)$, let $A_1\Theta$ and $A_2\Theta$ be the rows of $\Phi$, i.e.
$$\Phi=\begin{bmatrix}(A_1\Theta)^T\\(A_2\Theta)^T\end{bmatrix}$$
Is $\Phi$ a matrix-Gaussian random variable?
Clearly, $\Phi$ is a $2\times m$ matrix-valued random variable. Its expectation has rows equal to $A_1\mu$ and $A_2\mu$ respectively. Its covariance "matrix" is $\mathrm{Cov}(A_i\theta,A_j\theta)=A_i\Sigma A_j^T$ for $i,j=1,2$, so it has a size of $2\times2\times m\times m$. However, According to Wikipedia, a matrix-Gaussian random variable has two matrices related to the covariance, typically denoted by $U$ and $V$, which are the Kronecker factors of the full covariance matrix. I cannot see how the matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}A_1\Sigma A_1^T&A_1\Sigma A_2^T\\A_2\Sigma A_1^T&A_2\Sigma A_2^T\end{bmatrix}$$
can be expressed as a Kronecker product.
Is $\Phi$ really a matrix-Gaussian random variable?

I don't think it is a matrix-variate normal random variable.
Let $Z$ be $n\times1$ vector of i.i.d. $N(0,1)$ random variables such that $\Theta=\Sigma^{1/2}Z+\mu$.
Then $$\Phi^T=\begin{bmatrix}A_1 & A_2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}\Theta & \\ &\Theta
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}A_1\Sigma^{1/2} & A_2\Sigma^{1/2}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}Z & \\ & Z
\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}A_1\mu & A_2\mu
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
It remains to check whether $I_2\otimes Z$ is a matrix-variate normal random variable. But $\text{vec}(I_2\otimes Z)$ has covariance matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}I_n & 0 & 0 &I_n \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\I_n & 0 & 0 & I_n
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Suppose that this could be written in the $\underset{2\times2}{V} \ \otimes\ \underset{(2n)\times(2n)}{U}$ form. Then
$$\begin{bmatrix}I_n & 0 & 0 &I_n \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\I_n & 0 & 0 & I_n
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix} v_{11} U & v_{12} U \\ v_{21} U & v_{22} U \\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
By matching the two sides, each of the $v_{ij}U$ submatrix requires three $n\times n$ blocks of $U$ to be zero, and thus all elements of $U$ have to be zero. But the LHS has some elements being $1$. So this cannot be written in the $V\otimes U$ form.

So, a random matrix with jointly Gaussian entries is not necessarily matrix-Gaussian. Is that correct?

By considering $I_2\otimes Z$ itself, I don't believe so. @W.Zhu

$\Phi = \begin{bmatrix}
A_1 \\A_2
\end{bmatrix} \Theta$ is a linear transformation of a Gaussian vector, so it's still Gaussian.

This does not answer the question. You are stacking the columns $A_1\Theta$ and $A_2\Theta$ vertically, so the resulting matrix contains a single column, and it is indeed a vector-valued (with size $2m$) Gaussian random variable. But $\Phi$ has $A_1\Theta$ and $A_2\Theta$ as its rows and is a $2\times m$ matrix, and the question is whether it is a matrix-Gaussian random variable.
